# Finding first and last date that are in the same column filtered by value

Tags: powerbi, dax

The values are within one table. First column is ID which is repeated many times and second column is the date of when the ID was logged. How to find create through DAX another column or a measure to show when was the earliest date from date column that is connected to that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure=CALCULATE(MIN(Table[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[ID]))
```